# Rank in matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I have been told multiple things and just want to clear it up,
To find the rank of a matrix, is it just the number of leading entries when row reduced?

What does this mean?

Comment: Well, that's not what it *is*, what you are describing is just a way of computing it.

Comment: The rank of a matrix is the maximum number of linearly independent columns (or rows) of the matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think of matrices as functions between vector spaces, then the rank is the dimension of the range of the function.

But yes, a way to compute it is by counting the numbers of nonzero pivots in reduced row echelon form. This is because for every row of the matrix with a pivot, there is a vector in the range with a non-zero component in that row.